# How to pass multiple input directories to a hadoop command using a loop

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop-streaming

To run a script using *hadoop streaming* - I use a bash script that looks like this -

```
IP1="/data/hdp/f1/part-*"
IP2="/data/hdp/f2/part-*"
OP="/data/hdp/op"
hadoop jar $HADOOP_JAR_PATH \
-file $MAPPER_FILE -mapper "$PY $MAPPER_FILE" \
-input $IP1 -input $IP2 
-output $OP
```

How do I generalize this to a case where I have 20 input directories. One approach is specifying it as
 `-input $IP1 -input $IP2 -input $IP3 ... -input $IP20`

But I would want to know if we can use the shell variables and loops/arrays to get it done like this:

```
IP_LIST=${!IP*}
IP_CMD=''
for ip in $IP_LIST
do
    IP_CMD=$IP_CMD"-input $"$ip" "
done

IP_ARRAY=($IP_CMD)

hadoop jar $HADOOP_JAR_PATH \
-file $MAPPER_FILE -mapper "$PY $MAPPER_FILE" \
"${IP_ARRAY[@]}"
-output $OP
```

When I try this, I get an `Input path does not exist: hdfs://...` error.

**FULL COMMAND THAT I AM USING AS IS...**

```
IP1="/data/hdp/f1/part-*"
IP2="/data/hdp/f2/part-*"
OP="/data/hdp/op"
MAPPER_FILE="map_code.py"
REDUCER="reduce_code.py"

IP_LIST=${!IP*}
IP_CMD=''
for ip in $IP_LIST
do
    IP_CMD=$IP_CMD"-input $"$ip" "
done

hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash $OP

cmd="hadoop jar $HADOOP_JAR_PATH \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=00 \
-Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true \
-Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=\
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
-file $MAPPER_FILE\
-file $REDUCER  \
-mapper $PY $MAPPER_FILE\
-reducer $PY $REDUCER\
-output $OP -cacheFile $DC#ref\
$IP_CMD"
eval $cmd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make all the command as a string and after you finished use the `eval` command.

**In your example**-
add to IP_CMD the rest of the command and the use `eval $IP_CMD`

Comment: When I try, I get this error - `Found 1 unexpected argument on the command line [map_code.py]`. `map_code.py` is the value assigned to the variable `MAPPER_FILE`

Comment: I don't sure if the `mapper` param assumed that he get one or two params but to be consistent with the example that you said it works, try to wrap the `$py` and `$mapper_file` with `"` when you need to do that with slash - `\"$PY $FILE_MAPPER\"` - try to add it that the command will look like exactly like the command that worked.

Comment: That works! In fact, I wrapped all the variables (except `IP_CMD` - because I don't want it to expand with quotes to `"-input $IP1"`) with a `\"`, and it works.